# How to submit an app with companion device to AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

**Background:**
We are developing an application for one of our customer to go along with their device. The application by itself cannot do anything, and must be connected to the device via Wi-Fi in order to function.

**Question:**
Do we:

1. just submit the app the standard way, even though there's no way for Apple to really test the functionality of the app? 

   or
2. do we need to provide a test device to Apple to really test the functionality of the app? If so, what's the procedure for doing this?

Edit:
**Apple's Not-Very-Helpful Response**
While we cannot pre-approve apps, we can address compliance questions about specific App Store Review Guidelines or sections of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement (PLA). I understand that this may be a little frustrating and I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause, however, we may only answer specific questions concerning the following resources, unless the app is submitted for review so that we may test the functionality.

App Store Review Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

iOS Developer Program License Agreement: http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#agreements

Comment: More importantly, why are you asking us and not Apple?

Comment: You can add testing details in the note provided in itunes connect where you setup your application, its only for apple.. If apple couldn't test they will simply reject the application.. You should give an alert or so to the user that the app needs wifi connection..

Comment: If it is an in-house app, you should go for iOS Developer Enterprise Program https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: @KurtRevis We have sent Apple inquiry email, no feed back so far.

Comment: @Owen It's not an in-house app, the device is a camera and the buyers should be able to download the application from the App Store.

Comment: i see, so it's an app for interacting with the camera? I think you can write down the details in the note section when submitting the app to App Store, and make sure you leave your contact email address and phone number so they can contact you if they need your help for the app review. You might want to apply for MFi https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ although I guess it's not necessary in your case.

Comment: You are right MFi isn't needed for our use case as we use standard iOS technology. But it's still good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilites that have been reported.

- One is to submit a video of the app running with your companion device, with a complete walk-through of the app's functionality using that device.
- Another is to provide a device emulator as a test mode built into the app (perhaps requiring two devices).
- Another is to provide an demo account in the Review notes; and have that account wifi tunnel out to control a remote wifi device at your location, maybe with a webcam aimed at that device and viewable by Apple.
- Include proper contact info for that possibility where Apple may want you to send them a sample device for evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have source link for the abovementioned methods though?

Comment: Tried the video walk-through method, works most of the time (one Apple QA asked for a test device for one of the submissions), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue: a third-party device with which the app communicates. Without the device, the app is useless. One screen with one label. I submitted the app to the store, explaining what it does and how it communicates.

The app got approved 5 days later, without Apple asking any questions whatsoever.

Comment: That's an encouraging result, probably will use @hotpaw2's video walk-through method though, just to be safe.